# Xpath DOMDocument not returning data from node

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I am scanning a site using a dom document and receiving the `@src` attribute from the inner `img` element.

The html is:

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post">
      <img src="abc"/>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img src="abc1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Note: I am specifically not using `@src` in my `xpath`. Also, this is precisely the way i need it to be coded.**

Here is my php:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($file);
$XPath = new DOMXPath($document);
$Query = '//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]';

$posts = $XPath->query($Query);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if($XPath->evaluate("@src", $post))
    {
        $return[] = $XPath->evaluate("@src", $post)->item(0);
    }else{
        $return[] =  "";
    }
}
```

It's adding positions to the array `$return` however they are all empty array positions.

**My question is how do i make it output the data from the php code:**

```
$return[] = $XPath->evaluate("@src", $post)->item(0);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
$return[] = $XPath->evaluate("@src", $post)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I doubt your `div`'s have `src` attributes... Do they really, or are you searching deeper? (`evaluate("//@src")`)

Comment: Im searching against an `img` element within that `div` container. I updated my question

Comment: I added HTML to the question.

Comment: Updated question with the nodeValue code

Comment: @Wrikken Updated question. Please re-read.

Comment: @Wrikken Added a blank html div not containing an img element to show why i need it coded this way.

Comment: So, employ the `//@src` instead of `@src` I told you about. Should work. You could even use `//@src[1]` to stop at the first match, no use searching further.

Comment: @Wrikken I didn't realize you were speaking about the evaluate queries. Im going to check that now.

Comment: @Wrikken Im sorry I didnt see you actually wrote in your first comment that you updated it to `//@src`. It works though. Maybe you should make an answer out of it.

Comment: Well, quick remark (as I was surprised & testing it): might want to make it `.//@src` instead of `//@src` (note the leading `.`), so we were both a bit off ;)

Comment: This works out rather nicely (provided you don't need the attribute further, just the value):`foreach ($posts as $post) $return[] = $XPath->evaluate("string(.//@src[1])",$post);`. Automatic empty string & all if not found.

Comment: The selector needs to be `img/@src`, not just `@src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.//@src[1]`:

- `.`    => relative to node
- `//@`  => descendant
- `@src` => the src attribute
- `[1]`  => the first one.

You can even use `string(nodeset)` if you only care about the value (of course, leave that out if you need to be able to manipulate the attributes and use your `->item(0)` solution).

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
    $return[] = $XPath->evaluate("string(.//@src[1])",$post);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks as always. You always seem to be assisting me. I enjoy your thorough and methodical answers.